# Cannot read property length of undefined, Trying to build android apk

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

please assist me in resolving this error, I've been searching for a soultion and i could get any, i'm fearly new to ionic framework. i'm trying to build an android apk running the following command "ionic cordova build android" and i get this error.

[image: Error Message]

Tried most of the solutions I got from the portals, such updating plugins, reinstalling all your node-modules and so fought.

Below is my ionic info, please assist to point-out what i might be doing wrong or missing in my dev-enviroment.

[image: ionic info]

Comment: i stopped using  the cli because of it's endless problems . i use android stuio to generate APK and xcode to generate IPA

Comment: thanks for the hedds-up will give it try and see

Comment: @FarabiAbdelwahed but how can you get the android code without building the project ? I am facing this problem too.